# How to Access MS Team Files from Command Line

Tags: command-line, mac, microsoft-teams

`Context`: I would like to create folders and files for an existing MS Team from the command line as opposed to the GUI. I only have a beginner level understanding of the MS architecture.

`Question`: From the command line, how can I access the files of an MS team I belong to?

`MS Team Architecture`:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-architecture-solutions-posters

`Microsoft Teams files`:  storage location (Files shared in a channel) - SharePoint Online

`SharePoint via Powershell`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Why is this tagged Mac when all your other references, command line, powershell etc are Windows only?

Comment: @Tetsujin my operating system is macOS. that is why I tagged as mac. all the blogs I have seen refer me to use PowerShell via mac terminal. That is why I included PowerShell.

Comment: Hmm… I wasn't aware you could get powershell on Mac; apparently you can. I've never used it, sorry - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way could be to Sync the SharePoint document library locally to your PC and copy the files/folder to the sync location.
The sync engine will then copy to the Teams SharePoint for you.